# Receive-SFTPFile : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'RemoteFile'

Tags: powershell, sftp, powershell-cmdlet

I am using Transferetto module to download SFTP files, it is able to connect to server and list the server files but throwing error while downloading with below error:-
Receive-SFTPFile : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'RemoteFile'.
My script is like below:-

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process -Force
Import-Module Transferetto

$SftpClient = Connect-SFTP -Server '100.100.00.00' -Username 'FRG_100_22' -Password 'dfggrty'

$List = Get-SFTPList -SftpClient $SftpClient -Path '/FRG'
    Get-Childitem -Path "\\data\files" | Remove-Item
    $downloadedFiles = @()
    # Download multiple files into directory
    foreach($originalSFtpFile in $list) {

        $downloadedFile = Receive-SFTPFile -SftpClient $SftpClient -RemoteFile $originalSFtpFile -LocalPath "\\data\files" -LocalExists Overwrite -VerifyOptions Retry, None
        Write-Host "Downloaded file $($originalSFtpFile.Name) in folder  $($downloadedFile.LocalPath)"
        $downloadedFiles += ($downloadedFile)
    }

Disconnect-SFTP -SftpClient $SftpClient
```

Answer (score -1):

I used RemotePath instead of RemoteFile and it solved the problem.